# Angular: Handling array of checkboxes

Tags: angular

So I have an Angular app where one of my forms contains a list of checkboxes. Here is how I generate the checkboxes on the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of items;let x = index">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems[]" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems[x]" [value]="i.id" />
</div>
```

The format for my `items` is `{id: value, item_name: value}`, and `selectedItems` is just an array of the item ids.

My problem is during edit. So during edit I need to check the previously checked items during add. Now what happens is even if the value of `selectedItems[x]` is `null` the checkbox still appears to be checked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you leave your `items` and your `selectedItems` format here?

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, put the selected condition into your items JSON like this:

```
item: 
  {
    id: any,
    item_name: any,
    isSelected: Boolean,
  }[];
```

Then you can do something like this with your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of items;let x = index">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-{{x}}" [(ngModel)]="i.isSelected" [value]="i.id" />
</div>
```

But even if don't want to remodel your structure, when your `ngModel` is `null` or `undefined` it's not checked. In your case, as you said `selectedItems` is the array of items id it's might be the string of null like this `"null"` because in angular `undefined`, `null`, `''`, `0` and ... are false expressions.

Comment below if there was any problem so I can help you more.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up removing the `ngModel` and just updated the data using the `change` event of the checkbox, like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of items;let x = index">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems[]" (change)="onCheckChange(i, $event.target.checked)" [checked]="isItemChecked(i)" 
  [value]="i.id" />
</div>
```

Comment: Jed - can you share your onCheckChange and isItemChecked functions...
I am having the same issues. thx

Answer (score -2):

You can try using[checked] attribute binding property and pass value true/false.

```
item: 
  {
    id: any,
    item_name: any,
    isSelected: Boolean,
  }[];

<div *ngFor="let i of items;let x = index">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-{{x}}" [checked]="i.isSelected" [(ngModel)]="i.item_name" [value]="i.id" />
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that. But it seems that it gets overriden by the ngModel cause it still checks it.